# DataRowView issue when I try to Fill DropDownList from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, data-binding

```
Baglanti.FnkBaglan();
SqlCommand DropDown = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Yazar]", Baglanti.baglan);
SqlDataAdapter Adp = new SqlDataAdapter(DropDown);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
Adp.Fill(ds);
DrpYazarSec.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["Yazar_isim"].ToString() + " " + ds.Tables[0].Columns["Yazar_soyisim"].ToString();
DrpYazarSec.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["YazarID"].ToString();
DrpYazarSec.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
DrpYazarSec.DataBind();
```

I used this code but this error occured; Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView', Yazar_isim Yazar_soyisim adında bir özellik içermiyor. ( Has not Yazar_isim Yazar_soyisim )

Comment: I think you need to write your post in English, not Turkish

Comment: @Dusan: well, he needs to translate that error message. In fact, he should include the full exception, including stack trace.

Comment: Additional information: DataBinding: 'system.data.datarowview' does not contain a feature called Yazar_isim Yazar_soyisim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by this code:

```
DrpYazarSec.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["Yazar_isim"].ToString() + " " + 
                            ds.Tables[0].Columns["Yazar_soyisim"].ToString();
```

You cannot bind text to multiple columns, that is not possible.

However, you can join two columns in your query, for example:

```
SqlCommand DropDown = new SqlCommand("SELECT *, 
    [Yazar_isim] + ' ' + [Yazar_soyisim] AS [FullName]
    FROM [Yazar]", Baglanti.baglan);

...

DrpYazarSec.DataTextField = "FullName";
DrpYazarSec.DataValueField = "YazarID";

...
```